# How can I change the size of the image in this script?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I change the size of the image in this script to be larger? I see nothing in this script about height.

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Crown-Jewel-Coins-and-Currencies/2408904309248837" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't actually change the size of the image from that script. That script outputs an `iframe` of the Facebook social buttons, which you can't customize. What you can do, is use your own custom image and use the Facebook Graph API to open dialogs upon clicking on your custom button:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web